# Relationship between mapping cones and spectral sequences

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

I'm learning homological algebra using Weibel's book. And I have trouble in exercise 5.4.4:

> Let $f : B \to C$ be a map of filtered chain complexes. For each $r \geq 0$, define a filtration on the mapping cone $cone(f)$ by $$F_p cone(f)_n = F_{p-r} B_{n-1} \oplus F_p C_n.$$
> Show that $E^r_p (cone f)$ is the mapping cone of $f^r : E^r_p (B) \to E^r_p (C)$.

I'm not used to deal with mapping cone and spectral sequence, and I'm curious about the approach to this problem.

At first, I tried to represent $E^r_p (conef)$ explicitly by the construction process of $E^r_p$, but the indexing and calculation were so complicated that I doubted if it was the right way.

Is there a hint about this exercise?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What edition of the book are you reading? The numbering changes from one to another.